# Adding dashes to .number_format php function

Tags: php, function

I am a novice in working with the php language but have been learning over some time through testing and lots of time searching on the internet for examples and tutorials. Once in a while I get stumped with a task I just can't seem to figure out on my own. So I am asking that someone point me at least in the right direction in my current question.

I need to have the ability to add basically any character I want in a form field that will display the results I type in. Currently, the template uses the code below for the field and displays back only numbers. I need to upgrade or change it to allow any character I want.

Here it is

```
.number_format($price, 0, '.', ',')
```

Do I need to provide any additional info or does this get anyone's gears turning?

Much appreciated.

Comment: if you want to display any character why try to format/filter it at all? text fields already support any character you type in.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, does that mean removing the parameters like `'.'` and just leave the rest?

Comment: I don't know what "parameters like '.'" you mean. number_format, formats a number. If you want other characters that don't belong in a number, don't run it through number_format.

Comment: Sorry, I can't explain exactly what I mean in lamens terms but I think I get what you are saying. If I don't want specific characters only, don't use `number_format` since that's what controls what is displayed.

Comment: Read the [number_format()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) documentation. It returns a formatted number where the third param is used for the decimal place and the fourth is used for the thousands separator.